# registering custom environment in AzureML

Tags: azure

I am using the following code to register an environment using Azure ML SDK2 and getting the error shown below.

```
from azureml.core import Environment, Workspace
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

ws = Workspace.from_config()
args_ws = dict(subscription_id=ws.subscription_id, resource_group_name=ws.resource_group, 
               workspace_name=ws._workspace_name)
ml_client = MLClient(credential=DefaultAzureCredential(), **args_ws, enable_telemetry=False)

env_docker_conda = Environment(
    image="mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-cuda11.6-cudnn8-ubuntu20.04",
    conda_file="./py310gpu.yml",
    name="py310gpu",
)
ml_client.environments.create_or_update(env_docker_conda)
```

The error I am getting is

```
AttributeError: 'Environment' object has no attribute '_auto_increment_version'
```

I'd like to register and build the environment separate from the job/experiment.  What is the right way to do this using SDK2?

Updating based on the answer provided

```
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Environment
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

args_ws = dict(subscription_id="...",
               resource_group_name="...", workspace_name="...")
ml_client = MLClient(credential=DefaultAzureCredential(), **args_ws, enable_telemetry=False)

env_docker_conda = Environment(
    image="mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-cuda11.6-cudnn8-ubuntu20.04",
    conda_file="./py310gpu.yml", name="py310gpu",
)
ml_client.environments.create_or_update(env_docker_conda)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, the issue is the import of the Environment.
The [Environment class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-ai-ml/azure.ai.ml.entities.environment?source=recommendations&view=azure-python)  with the constructor you are trying to use comes from azure.ai.ml.entities package.
So the import should be:

```
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Environment
```